# Is there any way to create dynamic utility classes in css?

Tags: html, css, sass

Is there any way to do something like...
`<h1 class="pad-5">Some Heading</h1>`
to apply a padding of 5px to the `h1` tag.
And this should be dynamic. For example, If I write `class="pad-15"`, it should give padding of 15px.

And I want to do this by creating one single ruleset. Not by defining different classes of pad-5, pad-15 and so on individually.

In css file, it should be something like...

```
.pad-[$value]{
     padding: $value;
}
```

So, is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot do this with CSS. You could use a CSS preprocessor such as SASS or Less to generate a bunch of classes for you in a loop if you want. You could alternatively use JS to add styling based on the class name, though I would definitely not recommend it.

SASS (SCSS) example:

```
@for $i from 1 through 15 {
    .pad-#{$i} {
        padding: $i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a mixin (with Sass):

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin

Example:

```
@mixin pad($width) {
  padding: #{$width}px;
}
```

Application:

```
h1{
  @include pad(5);
}
```

Comment: can you use this in a class like OP asked? That would be helpful as I am also searching the same.

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul with Sass you can reference a mixin inside any selector (class, id, element) with the `@include` directive. I don't know if you can simply create a dynamic selector.